# Side effects to switching MatchParen off in vim Insert Mode

Tags: vim

I want vim to highlight the paren/bracket/brace that matches the one under the cursor in normal mode. When I switch to insert mode, though, I want the matching to stop. (It makes it impossible to see my bar cursor when there's a highlighted block cursor right next to it.)

This is easy enough to do:

> au InsertEnter * :NoMatchParen
>   au InsertLeave * :DoMatchParen

However, this combination of autocmds introduces a weird behavior that I can't live with: if I'm in a vsplit on the right, or a split on the bottom, and switch to the split at the left/top, and then enter insert mode, focus reverts to the other pane. This happens whether I enter insert mode immediately, or move the cursor around in normal mode first.

An especially weird thing is that focus is NOT jumping to the *most recent* pane. If I enter insert mode in the bottom/right pane, the cursor remains where it is.

I have tried a few combinations of WinEnter, CursorMoved and other events, but haven't found anything that doesn't either leave this behavior or introduce something even worse.

So, to phrase in the form of a question: how can I make this stop?

Comment: Are you looking for `set noshowmatch` ?

Comment: No. The showmatch functionality is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands `:DoMatchParen` and `NoMatchParen` of the matchparen plugin work internally using the `:windo` command, which unfortunatly leaves the cursor in the wrong window. This has been discussed in the vim-dev [list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/S23tTVfUONk/oQN9cYwvCQAJ) previously. There is no solution currently. You need to save the cursor position before calling those commands and then restore it afterwards.

Comment: That's good to know. Instead of turning MatchParen on and off, I can leave it on all the time, and just change the highlight color to match the background color in Insert Mode.